# Is APOE present in Lipid Rafts?

Tags: neuroscience

What evidence is there that APOE is present in lipid rafts (neurons or glial cells)?

I would be interested in any comparison between the APOE gene variants as well, but that is not required. I've looked around quite a bit for this but could only find apparently the background for a conference presentation (https://alz-journals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/alz.054511). The link is very vague on details.

However, I'm sure someone somewhere has looked at this question...